Can't install mediapipe via pip
Hey I want install mediapipe on my Mac via pip. After a short research I have seen that I need to install mediapipe-silicon.
So I tried to install it with
pip install mediapipe-silicon
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mediapipe-silicon (from versions: none)

ERROR: No matching distribution found for mediapipe-silicon
Python 3.12.3
pip 24.0
Mac OS 14.4.1
Chip M2 Max

I have solved problem with an environment on Python 3.11.4 and a pip version of 23.2.1. then Pip install works but crash by initializing the package. I have downgraded it to mediapipe==0.10.9 and know my application is running.
